# Detect keyboard press

Tags: python, events, keyboard

I want to make a program that runs a code when you just click on a button on a keyboard for example, I press A and some code runs, but I do not have to press enter or input it to run it. Just like in video games, your character moves if you press W. Sorry if it is worded badly, I am pretty confused about this.

Keep in mind please it's Python 2.7

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Keypress detection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36554353/keypress-detection)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am assuming you mean in the console and not in any gui like tkinter or something.

I'd suggest using pynput (pip install pynput)

with code similar to this

```
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

def on_press(key):
    print('{0} pressed'.format(
        key))

def on_release(key):
    print('{0} release'.format(
        key))
    if key == Key.esc:
        # Stop listener
        return False

while True:
    with Listener(on_press=on_press,on_release=on_release) as listener:
        listener.join()
```

word of warning:
The above code also catches exit keys so ctrl + c will not stop the console. for that you would need to implement something to break out of the While loop when ctrl+c is pressed.